# Ihow to get serial number of a hardware device using ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I was trying to fetch the device details,where i am unable to get serial number of the hardware device. Except serial number, I can fetch uuid of the device.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you could get:

```
Grab device related information, such as platform, and device model.

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
Methods

getDevice()

Get all device information.

Returns Object — returns cordova, model, platform, UUID, and version information
```

source: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/